Spring ApplicationEventListener not triggering on events
I'm using Spring ApplicationEventListener in my service to perform on-startup logics. I know, that I can use @PostConstruct annotation on the method, but, due to test-logic reasons it can't be applied to my code. Here is my listener:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationStartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private final SubscriptionService subscriptionService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        subscriptionService.onStart();
    }
}

It is not working (@PostConstruct does, though) - even if I have a breakpoint at method-level or inside it - it seems that no ApplicationReadyEvent is happening. I tried to replace that method with @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) annotation, but it still has no effect. Neither debug mode nor Events change are working and I'm clueless why it can be happening. Hope for the answer, feel free to ask any questions :)

Have you tried to catch other events (eg. ContextStartedEvent, ContextRefreshedEvent)  to check if the declaration of the listener is correct, using the ApplicationListener approach or the @EventListener one?

@FrancescoPoli Hi! Yep, I've tried to catch any type of Event (both in annotation and class), nothing is happening, it doesn't break on breakpoint

Below is the stack information that works normally.
onApplicationEvent:14, ApplicationStartupListener ()
onApplicationEvent:8, ApplicationStartupListener ()
doInvokeListener:176, SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster (org.springframework.context.event)
invokeListener:169, SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster (org.springframework.context.event)
multicastEvent:143, SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster (org.springframework.context.event)
publishEvent:421, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
publishEvent:378, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
ready:114, EventPublishingRunListener (org.springframework.boot.context.event)
lambda$ready$6:82, SpringApplicationRunListeners (org.springframework.boot)
accept:-1, 1090171402 (org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners$$Lambda$2028)
forEach:1541, ArrayList (java.util)
doWithListeners:120, SpringApplicationRunListeners (org.springframework.boot)
doWithListeners:114, SpringApplicationRunListeners (org.springframework.boot)
ready:82, SpringApplicationRunListeners (org.springframework.boot)
run:322, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
main:31, Application ()

Please do the checks:

ApplicationStartupListener is created by Spring Boot. The simplest way is remove @RequiredArgsConstructor and add a constructor with breakpoint, if execute to here mean created.
Add breakpoint at SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready function, make sure your application is really ready.


Hi! I've checked without @RequiredArgsConstructor and it's still not working, so then it is not creating as a Bean or not visible with Spring ComponentScan - tommorow I will do a deeper research and bring back results, thx for help :)

Good morning! Checked with second check, ready function is triggering

How about first check? ApplicationStartupListener is created?

Nope That's the first time I see such a bug . I've tried to create it through configuration and direct Bean-creation, but it is not working too. Thrilling bug as it is :)

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
app.addListeners(new ApplicationStartingListener());
app.run(args);
}
you can add listener like this.
